# Managed package gives lightning out syntax error after adding the handling of an application event

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-out

**I have**:

2 Lightning components

1 Lightning application (with dependency out)

2 Visualforce pages that host the lightning components through the lightning out application

**What it does**:

1 lightning component shows list of items and can redirect to the other lightning component showing more data for a particular item

The visualforce pages are there to have the functionality in classic UI

**The situation**:

Everything works in my DEV org where I create the managed package.

In other orgs the lightning components still work in Lightning Experience but when viewed in the Visualforce pages they don't show up anymore because of a syntax error:

> VM429:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position
>   0xhr.onreadystatechange @
>   lightning.out.delegate.js?v=qnVOSqP_GYth6AWC2fT1jQ:83

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var config = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                        // save the delegate version to local storage
                        localStorage.lightningOutDelegateVersion = config.delegateVersion;
```

xhr.responsetext:

```
while(1);↵*/{"defaultHandler":"function() {$A.clientService.hardRefresh()}","event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:noAccess","attributes":{"s":1,"v":{"values":{}}},"eventDef":{"s":2,"v":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:noAccess","type":"APPLICATION","xs":"G","superDef":{"s":3,"v":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:applicationEvent","type":"APPLICATION","xs":"G","attributes":{}}},"attributes":{"redirectURL":{"s":4,"v":{"name":"redirectURL","type":"aura://String","xs":"G"}}}}}},"exceptionEvent":true}/*ERROR*/
```

This clearly has to do with the lightning out functionality.

Everything was still working in other orgs before the last release.

I only added the handling of an application event in the visualforce pages so the handleNavUrl and the eventService part so that navigation events that in lightning experience are handled by the one.app are handled by the Visualforce container in classic UI.

```
    <script>
var handleNavToURL = function(event){
    var theURL = event.getParam("url");
    console.log('Got URL from component: ' + theURL);
    if (theURL.includes('/apex/')) {
        window.top.location.assign(theURL);
    } else {
        window.open(theURL, '_blank');
    }
};

$Lightning.use("MYNAMESPACE:MYLOAPP", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent(
        "MYNAMESPACE:NewsFeed",
        {
            label : "NewsFeed",
            recordId : "{!account.id}",
            sObjectName : "Account",
            newsFeedCount : "4"
        },
        "NewsFeed",
        function(cmp) 
        {
            $A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "force:navigateToURL", "handler" : handleNavToURL})
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

I want to mention again that I don't have any problem at all in my own developer org.

It only gives a problem when it's packaged and installed in another org.

Anyone an idea?

PS: I changed some names in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the previous suggested answer, access="GLOBAL" was not missing in the components but it was missing in the lightning app.

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outAppUnstyled" access="GLOBAL">
    // My dependencies
</aura:application>
```

It took several weeks chatting with multiple tiers of Salesforce support to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is access control kicking in on MYNAMESPACE:NewsFeed - there is nothing in the linkage from VF -> LO -> Lightning Out that would automatically understand that the calling VF page is in the same namespace as the component. To confirm this please change MYNAMESPACE:NewsFeed to have `<aura:component access="GLOBAL">` and retest the scenario.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I already have access="GLOBAL" inside the component though.

Comment: We are investigating - I do not believe there is anything in your code that is causing this and it looks like a system level issue.

Comment: OK. If it helps I shared my github repository of the managed package code in the support case with Sandeep. Although it's a public repository, I'd prefer not to share it on a public site.

Comment: I just noticed that you are using an undocumented ($A.eventService.addHandler) and unsupported API to wire up handleNavToURL(). We're going to need to change that (there is a pattern that is supported) but I am not convinced that would fix this access check related issue (can't tell what component, event, attribute, etc is triggering this server side exception since its not part of the aura:noAccess event's attributes. Does the problem persist if you temporarily comment out the call to $A.eventService.addHandler()?

Comment: The error remains if I comment out that line and repackage. I'll try to backtrack my changes some more until I get it working again.
Could you tell me what pattern is supported?

Comment: @DougChasman, you haven't mentioned what the approved pattern is for trapping lighting events in Visualforce pages.  Can you point us at the documentation?

Comment: Any solutions??